# Calling a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

Take a scenario as shown below:

```
Class A : public B
{

private:
C obj
public:
A()

}

Class B
{
B(int , int)
}


Class C
{
C();
C( int , int)
}
```

Is there a way by which I can call the non default constructor when initialising an object of Class A?

I know that to initialize B, I could do something like:

```
A():B(int, int) //but what if I want to initalise C also?
```

Comment: Does your C++ book not discuss this detail of initializer lists?

Comment: Perhaps you meant `class`, and have semicolons in place.

Comment: not sure what you meant Gman..but my question is worded right.

Comment: @Sii: C++ is case sensitive and requires a semicolon to terminate class declarations. If your question is worded correctly then you need to go back to your C++ book and review some syntax fundamentals.

Comment: @Charles and @Gman: My apologies, I was so engrossed on the problem I was dealing with, I didnt notice that I had missed the semicolons while writing the scenario above to convey my problem clearly.(not the case with code I am dealing with). Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Sii: Generally, if you post code you should always cut and paste it from files that you are actually trying to compile. Otherwise you will waste people's time as they help you with "problems" that you aren't actually experiencing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both base classes and data members can appear in the initializer list:

```
A() : B(42, 42), obj(42, 42) { }
```

Comment: I did try this may be its just not the constructor problem.Thanks for feedack.

Answer (score 1):

`A() : B(int, int), obj(int, int) {}`

Answer (score 1):

You do like this:

```
A(): B(int, int), obj(int, int)
```